# Dynamic drive dilemna

Tags: windows-7

I tried to install Win7 on a new laptop which had Win 8.1 already installed but Win7 asked for a driver it didn't say which one but it wouldn't install over Win 8. Frustrated I deleted the partition with Win 8 thinking i could create a new one for Win7. That was a huge mistake because i didn't know anything about Dynamic drives.

Now I can't restore Win8 cuz I didn't do a backup and the laptop didn't come with any CD's.

How can I get rid of that Dynamic drive BS so i can install Win7?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded a windows 8.1 trial from microsoft then used the repair option to use Diskpart to delete all partitions on the Dynamic drive then partitioned the drive and formatted it to ntfs partition.

Next i downloaded the Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool and created a bootable USB drive using a Windows 7 iso. That did the trick and i finally got Win7 installed.

Now i have to find Win7 drivers for my hardware, this part is turning out to be a greater challenge.